Flask + Celery + RabbitMQ - kombu.exceptions.operationalerror errno 111 connection refused
below the are code snippets for flask+celery+rabbitMQ,the issue is they are working in local ,but when I deployed on EC2 instance ,I am getting errno 111 connection refused .
start_celery.py
from celery import Celery, Task
from flask import Flask
import os
from config import *

def create_celery(app):
    class ContextTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery = Celery(app.name, task_cls=ContextTask)
    celery.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    celery.conf.task_default_queue = SERVER_TYPE + '_queue'
    celery.conf.task_default_exchange = 'celery:' + SERVER_TYPE
    celery.conf.task_default_routing_key = SERVER_TYPE + '.task'
    celery.conf.broker_connection_options = {'broker_pool_limit': 0}
    celery.conf.broker_transport_options = {'confirm_publish': True}
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery

    return celery


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    CELERY=dict(
        broker_url=RABBITMQ_URL,
        result_backend='rpc://',
        task_ignore_result=False,
    ))
celery_app = create_celery(app)

celery_impl.py
from celery import shared_task

from backend.queue_manager.subscriber_job_types import SUBSCRIBER_JOBS

from queue_manager.start_celery import celery_app
import os
from config import *


class Celery:

    def publish(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.subscriber.delay(task, args, kwargs)
        exchange_name = 'celery:' + SERVER_TYPE
        routing_key = SERVER_TYPE + '.task'
        queue_name = SERVER_TYPE + '_queue'
        return self.subscribe.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, exchange=exchange_name,
                                          routing_key=routing_key, queue=queue_name)

    @shared_task(bind=True)
    def subscribe(self, *args, **kwargs):
        task = kwargs.get('task')
        kwargs.pop('task')
        val = SUBSCRIBER_JOBS[task]["worker"](*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['task'] = task
        return val


and the app created in start_celery.py has been imported in main file where app.run is being used.
RABBITMQ_URL is varying based on enviornments and yeah I checked the relavant inbound and outbound rules for those instances and they both rabbit mq container and code container are accessible to each other for all ports
Tried various solutions online such as
from .celery import app as celery_app
all = ('celery_app',)
and some other but none of them are working

Check if your flask server can talk to your celery work in your ec2 instance. I faced this issue when I used docker and had my celery worker running  on netowork_mode: 'host' and my server was using the container network.
#compose.yml
      server:
        build: .
        container_name: slice_backend
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
          - .:/app
    
      celery:
        build: .
        container_name: celery_worker
        command: celery -A tasks worker 
        volumes:
          - .:/app
        depends_on:
          - server
          - rabbitMQ
        environment:
          - CELERY_BROKER_URL=pyamqp://guest:guest@rabbitMQ:5672//
          - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=rpc://
        network_mode: host


I have started my celery worker in flask server.py itself using subprocess command, not as a seperate container.They both run in single container

It finally worked when I changed task annotation to celery_app.task from shared_task
